# How to extract the element in a list column based on the value in another column using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

How can I find the element in a list column based on the value in another column using purrr?

For instance, imagine I have a simple tibble with 2 columns and 2 rows.  The second column is a list column with both rows showing the "letters" vector as a list.  The first column shows the element of the list that I would like to extract.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lets <- tibble(posn = 1:2,
               lets_list = list(letters, letters)) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

returns:

```
Observations: 2
Variables: 2
$ posn      <int> 1, 2
$ lets_list <list> [<"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f
```

Using the purrr package, I can execute the following command:

```
lets %>% 
  mutate(lets_sel = map_chr(lets_list, 2))
```

which returns a new column, "lets_sel" with a value of "b" as this is the second element of the letters vector:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   posn lets_list  lets_sel
  <int> <list>     <chr>   
1     1 <chr [26]> b       
2     2 <chr [26]> b
```

However, I would like to use the value in the **posn** column to specify which element of the *lets_list* list to return.

I've tried this command without success.

```
lets %>% 
  mutate(lets_sel = map_chr(lets_list, posn))

> lets %>% 
+   mutate(lets_sel = map_chr(lets_list, posn))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector.
```

As well as numerous variations, such as:

```
lets %>% 
  mutate(lets_sel = lets_list[[posn]])
```

but this returns this incorrect result with "b" and "b" instead of "a" and "b":

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   posn lets_list  lets_sel
  <int> <list>     <chr>   
1     1 <chr [26]> b       
2     2 <chr [26]> b
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `map2_chr` since this takes two arguments

```
lets %>% 
   mutate(lets_sel = map2_chr(lets_list, posn,~.x[.y]))

 A tibble: 2 x 3
   posn lets_list  lets_sel
  <int> <list>     <chr>   
1     1 <chr [26]> a       
2     2 <chr [26]> b
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Onyambu.  Your solution worked perfectly.